# Display brightness and resolution issues with an Nvidia GT520M

Tags: 11.10, resolution, screen, brightness, nvidia-optimus

I have a notebook with NVidia GT520M (which uses Optimus technology) and after a long and bloody fight I finally put it to work through Ironhide.

Last night I let my notebook be out of battery by accident. After reboot and login, the default screen changed from 1366x768 to 1024x768 and the screen brightness init with 0 (screen totally black, brightness adjusted by the keyboard controls). Note that the login screen is Ok, perfect resolution and brightness...

How can I change back this values? And what happened :-T ?

Thank you all!!

Notes:

- I can't access NVidia settings, always crash Ironhide.
- When I change the resolution by xrandr or "Screen" interface it'll ok, but I always lost the configuration after reboot.
- After I install Ironhide for the first time, I reboot the system several times, and it was ok.

Comment: Have you activated Power Management through Ironhide?

Comment: Yes, I do... Now I've uninstalled Ironhide and still got this issue... :-/

Comment: That lets suppose something is wrong with Xorg config. Did you check xorg.conf file? When you login native resolution and display options change from default to customized. See if something was appended by accident to this file.
see also this wiki, to disable nvidia card temporarily. This will show us if the problem is related to Nvidia card or not.
https://wiki.edubuntu.org/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15

Answer (score 1):

Since the PM feature of Ironhide uses ACPI calls, it's possible that the power loss caused some inconsistency in the ACPI state.

Try pulling out the battery and AC adapter and leave it for a few (5?) minutes. After that, the ACPI state should be reset. Then try booting from a Live CD or Live USB. If that works, try to boot into your installation.

If the Live session works, but your installation does not, try to uninstall the nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

Comment: If your problem is not solved by this, please [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/kern.log` files.